# haproxy, capture length, and redirect

Tags: haproxy

I have an haproxy instance that redirects certain 301 GET requests.  Unfortunately, those requests are being truncated at 1024 bytes.

After much reading and experimenting, I believe the issue is the length of what is captured by `capture.req.uri`, which is 1024.  But I've not succeeded in increasing that number.  I'm quite open to pointers.

Here are the most relevant snippets from my `haproxy.cfg`:

```
global
    tune.bufsize 131072
        tune.maxrewrite 65536

defaults

frontend www-https
    bind 1.2.3.4:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/ssl/

    declare capture request len 16382
    declare capture response len 16382
    http-request capture capture.req.uri len 16382

    acl redirect_canonical ssl_fc_sni -i myname.example.com
    http-request  redirect  code 301  location  https://www.example.com%[capture.req.uri]  if\
 redirect_canonical
```

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Two lines for match and rewrite are then required.

First, a rewrite if the query string is present:

```
http-request redirect location %[path,map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map)]?%[query] code 301 if { path,map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map) -m found } { query -m found }
```

Then, a rewrite if the query string is absent:

```
http-request redirect location %[path,map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map)] code 301 if { path,map(/etc/haproxy/redirects.map) -m found } ! { query -m found }
```

Your map file would be paths only.